# Kali installation failing at "Select and Install software"

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, system-installation

I am trying to install Kali Linux onto VirtualBox virtual machine, but for some reason, I always get this error every time I try:

[image]

It can't be anything wrong with my computer, as I recently needed to reset my PC and it's still not working. I saw somewhere it might be something wrong with the network settings but am really confused as to what to do. I'd greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you went with the default VDI disk image size of 8 GB when you created the virtual machine in VirtualBox, that you used the default partitioning of the disk etc., and that you later tried to install the Xfce4 desktop and the default set of tools (the default option), then I would *expect* the package installation step to fail at some point due to running out of space.

The [installation documentation for Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/hard-disk-install/) says that

> On the higher end, if you opt to install the default Xfce4 desktop and the `kali-linux-default` metapackage, you should really aim for **at least 2048 MB of RAM** and **20 GB of disk space**.

Creating a 20 GB disk image or larger will allow you to install the tools and finish the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the "Select and install software" part and move to the GRUB Bootloader installation.
Once done, login to single user mode and run these in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kali-desktop-xfce

sudo apt-get install kali-linux-default
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve got the same problem few days back, and my solution was that when I was creating bootable drive, windows deffender flagged some of its shipped software as malware. So I disabled it, created bootable USB again and tried to install it once more. Zero problems.