How to fix a Kali installation persistently failing at various installation steps after partitioning
Kali linux distribution installer fails repeatedly at various installation steps during expert installation after disk partitioning which is necessary in my case to preserver some prior partitioning on the HP laptop used including a dual windows installation that functioned well ind dual boot with Debian which I'm trying to replace with a Kali fresh installation.
There is a somewhat similar failure on older Kali distribution and on a VM:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633050/kali-installation-failing-at-select-and-install-software[][1]
My failure message and behavior is similar (most failures occur during the same step but sometimes even during the prior step  or after ) to that from an older Kali distribution installation from a prior question but that is related to VMs; this isn't that case and there's plenty of space on all partitions (root, home, etc) so that's unlikely the cause of the failure.
I repeated the installation attempt each time after a hardware reboot several times with following variations each time, considering download (https or torrent) successful checksum passed all burning successful no errors:

tried from different 32GB flash memory sticks formated FAT32 exFAT;
tried from a 4.7 DVD-RW using an external USB Blue-ray drive;
tried kali-linux-2024.3-installer-amd64.iso;
tried kali-linux-2024.2-installer-amd64.iso;
tried kali-linux-2024.3-live-amd64.iso;
tried kali-linux-2024.3a-installer-purple-amd64.iso

In some cases after the installation step failure I would as recommended by the installer check the integrity of the installer media, which sometimes passed, sometimes failed. But when I check the installer media on a different debian laptop it shows no errors.
I've installed several other linux distributions over many years various computers and maybe occasionally had some media installation error that didn't reoccur on second attempt but never something like this. I only found a more recent similar occurence on the internet but that doesn't seem to have a solution that works for my situation.
an-installation-step-failed-software-selection

I'll keep trying but I'm running out of combinations and patience so any more ideas?
 partitioning no disk/fsck errors and enough space

Please [edit] your question and show us the actual error message. We need it in the question not somewhere else. If the linked question is edited or deleted, for example, yours will no longer make sense. Plus, you have only linked us to a "similar" error, we need the exact error you are getting.


In some cases after the installation step failure I would as recommended by the installer check the integrity of the installer media, which sometimes passed, sometimes failed. But when I check the installer media on a different debian laptop it shows no errors.

Your laptop has a severe hardware problem. This might literally be defective RAM (that's far less often the reason than people claim online these days, but here, large checksumming operations sometimes failing wrongfully: exactly the diagnostic), or a fundamental problem with PCIe or USB.
I'd much rather blame the nvme here (because SSDs by principle age, and you can ask them about their integrity, and business laptop SSDs are unlikely to lie, and SSDs are cheap and easy to replace), but integrity checks of external media failing on your laptop but not on other machines makes your RAM or the buses between removable media and RAM the only common denominators.

maybe occasionally had some media installation error that didn't reoccur on second attempt but never something like this.

You have had data integrity errors before and continued to work with the hardware?! OK, that basically means any data on your laptop is likely to have some unnoticed errors.
Do a RAM check (memtest86+). Hopefully it will point to errors in RAM you can replace! Otherwise, you'd have to look into logs on PCIe integrity data, and finding a problem there would only be solvable by replacing the main board.
Anyways, nothing here is specific to UNIX/Linux; it's really pretty definitely a hardware issue.

It's unlikely to be the hw as I'm using this HP laptop daily for about 2y bought new, and until now I had no significant failures (just few occasional halts maybe) in dual boot DebianSkole and Windows10; I just wanted to try replace it with Kali while keeping the same partitioning and dual boot. In the meantime I also found a recent bug report that seems the same error, and my own workaround https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=9007

As said everything points to it being hardware. Glad to hear that's not the case! Can't see a link to your workaround there? (testing your RAM doesn't hurt anyone, so I'd still do that even if you're convinced this is a software bug)

After persisting another day at it, with few other installation attempts variation I succeeded with kali-linux-2024.2-installer-amd64.iso from one of the same USB flashmemory stiks I used before, but as I tried so many combinations over a week I don't even remember if I tried this one before. But it didn't work by using the installer normally but I applied all steps from the expert installer up to including the Select Software step but from which I left deselected all the desktop environments (no Gnome KDE Xfce); crossed my fingers then it muddled through somehow, then I did the grub install then finished the installation and rebooted only without GUI xwindows but only in text console terminal, which worked. Then I installed from there the xfce desktop environment through the usual:
sudo apt install task-xfce-desktop

Then i did a full upgrade, as I wasn't on last release, although not sure if that was relevant. Eventually worked but it's strange as I never experienced this before as all my prior linux installations worked from the installer itself without the need for workarounds.

that sounds like it was pure luck, to be honest, since all these other things work for other people. It really still sounds like RAM problems, and you had a lucky run where you didn't use the physical RAM that was broken, maybe?
